# ASP.NET runtime error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

```
Line 16:   <system.web>
Line 17:     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
Line 18:     <authentication mode="Forms">
Line 19:       <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
Line 20:     </authentication>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The error's pretty self-explanatory - what's your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a backup directory of a previous version stored in the project folder and not excluded from project? It might happen in such a case. If that's the case then remove the "web.config" file from the previous version.